# jira confluence API change timetracking values

Tags: node.js, jira

I use nodeJS with jira-client 6.21 https://www.npmjs.com/package/jira-client

API options here https://jira-node.github.io/typedef/index.html#static-typedef-JiraApiOptions

I need change timetracking value on some issues, just a "Remaning" field. How to do this?

In my case I do :

1. Search issues like this :

   `` const res = await jira.searchJira(`status = "Closed" AND project = "${projectkey}" `,{maxResults : maxsearch}); ``
2. Dump result to console, and get issues objects, with timetracking fields like :

`timetracking: { remainingEstimate: '0m', timeSpent: '15m', remainingEstimateSeconds: 0, timeSpentSeconds: 900 }`

When I try to change with update method  `updateIssue()`, have an error like

```
StatusCodeError: 400 - {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"timetracking":"Field 'timetracking' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the "Time tracking" field is missing on the "edit issue" screen for the respective issue type.

A JIRA administrator needs to place the JIRA "Time Tracking" field on the issue screens:

1. -> Projects -> "Project Name" -> Project settings (left pane, bottom) -> Screens (left pane, middle)
2. For all screen configuration schemes:

   1. For all screens in the scheme:

      1. -> Configure Screen
      2. Scroll to the bottom of the list
      3. Add field "Time Tracking"

cf. e.g. https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/REST-API-Original-Estimate-Create-Issue/qaq-p/860192